# How do i get the title of a table view cell in a different view controller in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm currently using a table view and table view cells in a menu. When you click on one of the cells, it uses a segue inside storyboard to take you to a different view controller depending on which cell you click. They are all different links and the same view controllers except that I change which link opens on which view controller. I know this defeats the purpose of OOP because I'm having individual view controllers do pretty much the same task instead of not having one link opener view controller. How do I get the names of the table cells dynamically in the view controller after a segue?

Comment: Get the destination segue controller and pass it the title of the cell that performed the segue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)